# Bulk lens material for NIR & MWIR, cheap, non-toxic, thermally resistant

Tags: optics, material-science

I'm looking for a material to make big (30cm diameter) lenses for most of the IR spectrum beginning at 800nm upwards, at least to 8um.

The material should be easy to come by (as in: cheap and non-restricted), non-toxic, non-water soluble, thermally resistant to 500°C, non-monocrystalline (though that should be covered by cheap and big).

What I do **not** need (but don't shun): high refractive index, low chromatic aberration, available prefabbed as lenses.

With the above in mind, I'll also accept shells with the above  parameters, filled with a fluid or gas that does the actual refracting, as that might be cyclable to keep the temperature down. Still non-toxic and freely available, though. Or the other way round, a refracting material that plays well with an IR transparent fluid that could be used to cool things down.

Zinc selenide, zinc sulfide, diamond or thallium bromoiodide fit the bill on the spectral issues, but fail multiple of my other stipulations.

I am looking for a cheap material - I am aware that this usually means non-optics-quality - please feel free to contribute materials that usually are deemed too absorbing or too much variation in refractive index over different wavelengths, or too small refractive index for short focal length etc. The goal is to have a big lens that approximately focuses thermal wavelengths without itself melting.

Any comprehensive materials database that has a reverse-search ability for transmission wavelengths (and ideally also refractive index) would also be appreciated.

Comment: Big, cheap, high quality lenses are almost by definition not a thing. Particularly across such a broad range of wavelengths...

Comment: @JonCuster ... Which is exactly why i left the third descriptor (high quality) out. Low quality will suffice. Many plastics are actually spot on, if not for the thermal requirement.

Comment: @bukwyrm germanium is not viable for your wavelength range as it only starts to become viable after 1.7 um and probably not even until 2um. The measurement data I could find was not accurate enough after 1.7 um for the k value to determine the point at which it's truly viable. 30 cm is quite a lot of material. Also most materials transparent at 0.9 or 1 um will have problems after 5um.

Comment: @BobvandeVoort You are right. I'll alter the question. Thank you!

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: Anything polycrystalline will scatter at grain boundaries (for example zinc oxide ingots). That is why amorphous materials like glass are good for windows, optics, etc.

Comment: @bukwyrm one of the most extensive databases is refractiveindex.info. Also I would check for something like immersion oil maybe not super cheap but could work. Most other materials are just not going to be easy to find. But still you can't use oil without a container.